# Installing PublicationMapping extension for Web 8

Tags: cme, gui-extensions, web8

I'm trying to install the recently released PublicationMapping extension to work with TopologyManager on Web 8 https://community.sdl.com/developers/tridion_developer/m/mediagallery/1309

After performing all the steps as mentioned in the distribution documentation, the CME refuses to load (stuck in Loading) and I get see the following error in console :

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**

I would associate this with perhaps a typo in the configuration and invalid XML but I double checked the snippets that I added to System.config and they are valid xml items.

The interesting bit is that if I comment out the Model entries, the CME loads just fine.

Note that, it's a vanilla installation of Web 8 and there are no publications defined yet, would that be a problem?

-Kunal

Comment: I probed the extension and it works perfectly. Have you tried to create a publication to see if it solves the problem?. It seems an issue with some xml configuration text. If you have copy/pasted from  the doc, maybe a hidden character is causing the fault. I use to type all the configuration to avoid these problems. Have you increased the "modification" value to avoid cache?

Comment: I'll try creating a publication and see if help resolve the problem. Thank you for your inputs Raul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mea Culpa! The problem was missing a virtual directory for the Model which explains the problem solving itself when commenting the **model** section of the extension.

But I do wish that the errors showing up in CME would be a bit less cryptic.